# Laravel 5 Homestead/Vagrant issue

Tags: vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

by default vagrant clears the existing network interfaces:

> ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...

How can I prevent that? I tried to fix that since hours but can't get it to work. For example i edited the homestead.rb file and changed

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: settings["ip"] ||= "192.168.10.10"
```

to

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: settings["ip"] ||= "192.168.10.10", auto_config: false
```

But it still keeps doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop it from clearing existing network config you should comment line 64

```
b.use ClearNetworkInterfaces
```

in file action.rb located in ~\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.7.4\plugins\providers\virtualbox\action.rb

Hope this helps.
P.S. even with this I couldn't setup Homestead on windows 10 with virtualbox 5 due to some error with mounting shared folders.. Still looking for some solution.
Edit: Mount problem was with Vagrant 1.7.3, upgrade to 1.7.4 fixed it

Cheers,
Kristijan